# TTL in sql express db

Tags: sql, sql-server-express, ttl

I need to TTL option in my sql express db' table. For example- I have a ***exampletable*** in my db. I want to set ttl on one week in this.
Can I do that there?

Best regards.

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server Express?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373695/is-there-any-option-like-time-to-live-in-sql-server

Comment: I have seen, but... I need more details.